# flickr API calls

Tags: call, flickr, api-key

im interested how many api calls per second or per minute i can do with my flickr API Key?

is there a limit or is it unlimited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unlimited: http://developer.yahoo.com/flickr/

> To make Flickr web service calls, you
>   must get an application key. There are
>   no set restrictions on the number of
>   calls your application can make.

Answer (score 1):

it is unlimited.
you can genrate your flickr key from 
https://www.flickr.com/services/apps